# Statisitical Test for comp of multiple ordinal scaled groups, No NV

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-test

I would like to compare median of continuous data in multiple ordinal scaled groups, that are not normally distributed. Additionally, the samples within each group are partially dependent to samples in another group. I would also prefer to not exclude any samples.

Example:  I would like to compare the median of different human age groups. But I don't have samples from every human being for every age group, only from some of then.

Which statistical test would be suitable for this kind of task?